# How does Unity calculate the "center of mass" of a humanoid?

Tags: unity

Unity's [documentation for `HumanPose.bodyPosition` states](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HumanPose-bodyPosition.html):

> The center of mass is approximated using a human average body parts mass distribution.

What, specifically, does this mean?

It is not any of the following:

- The origin of the "Hips" bone.
- The middle of the skinned mesh's bounds.

I've found other people asking this question, but without any answers:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-does-unity-calculate-animators-center-of-mass-animator-bodyposition.495527/

Comment: have you found the calculation method?